# Javascript Conflict - lightbox and slider

Tags: javascript, lightbox, dreamweaver, conflict

So I'm pretty new to web design and Dreamweaver, but I've managed to put something fairly solid together. The only problem I'm having is that my two main javascripts for images - one slider and one lightbox gallery - are canceling each other out. If one works, the other cannot. Here's the code at the head. Any advice?

```
<!-- Style sheets themes for the Nivo Slider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider/themes/pascal/pascal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider/themes/orman/orman.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- Main Styles Sheet for the Primento theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!-- Google Webfonts - Other fonts can be installed - http://www.google.com/webfonts -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400,400italic,700'     rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<!--script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script-->
<!--script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script-->


<!-- Nivo Slider -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>  

<script src="engine/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="engine/js/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Are `js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` and `engine/js/jquery.min.js` different versions?

Comment: Yeah - try taking out that `engine/js/jquery.min.js` inclusion and see what that fixes. My bet is that the second declaration of jQuery blows away plugins for the first.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the second instance of jquery. That is likely re-initializing the jQuery object, causing the page to fail.

You only need one instance of jQuery on the page. It looks like the plugins you are using are older (i.e. pre-1.9), so you should try an older version of jQuery. If 1.7.x doesn't work, try a 1.8.x version. Version 1.9 removes several features that may prevent the plugins from working.

Comment: When I remove the second instance (jquery.min.js), it just makes the other javascript work instead.